# How to select 2-year time range based on a date - MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, mysql-workbench

I know how to select several days based on a date:

```
WHERE 
    date_column > adddate('2021-09-29', -100)
AND 
    date_column < '2021-09-29'
```

The query above select the data where `date_column` is between 100days before `2021-09-29` and `2021-09-29`.

My question is can I use the same pattern/syntax for `year` and how to do it? Is it something like `adddate('2021-09-29', -2y)`?

I know I can do something like `date_column BETWEEN '2021-09-29' - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND '2021-09-29'`, but I don't want to use this syntax, can I use something similar to the syntax in the top example because I'll need it in my Python code? Thanks.

Comment: Try this one `ADDDATE('2021-09-29', INTERVAL -2 YEAR)` instead,  there isn't any need to use `date BETWEEN`

Comment: @groovy_guy not `INTERVAL 2 YEAR` but `INTERVAL -2 YEAR`

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes exactly :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DATE_ADD('2021-09-29', INTERVAL -2 YEAR)`. [See this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

You could do something like this:

```
MAKEDATE(YEAR('2021-09-29') + 2, DAYOFYEAR('2021-09-29'))
```

Any date arithmetic you do "yourself" needs to be tested carefully for leap-year edge cases. Not worrying about those edge cases is the biggest and best reason to use the built-in date arithmetic operations. Lest your project be featured on https://worsethanfailure.com/ , which you do not want to happen.

(They do have strange syntax, eh?)